# Swift passing arrays between 2 tableviews. Returns nil instead

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, xcode6

I am pretty new to SWIFT coding. My intention is to pass 2 arrays with values from Viewcontroller1 to Viewcontroller2. But it returns me nil value in Viewcontroller2. Can someone advise me please?

Here is the partial code in ViewController1.

```
@IBAction func solve(sender: AnyObject) {
        //pass information to the nextviewcontroller
         func prepareForSegue ( segue: UIStoryboardSegue!, sender: AnyObject!) {
        if (segue.identifier == "Solve") {
        var svc = segue!.destinationViewController as ViewController2

        svc.toPass = self.force
            svc.toPass2 = stiffness

        }
        }
```

Here is the partial code in ViewController2.

```
class ViewController2: UITableViewController {

    var toPass:[String]!
    var toPass2:[String]!

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

             println(self.toPass)
                println(self.toPass2)
            // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        }
```

The full code can be found in here. https://github.com/cherrythia/SWIFTpassingarrays/blob/master/README.md

Comment: I don't get the first code. Why do you have a function inside the function? And also please post any necessary code directly in this question since external links can change quickly making the question incomprehensible in the future.

Comment: Are both values null or is it one of them(force/stiffness)

Comment: The first function is suppose to do prepareforsegue when user click on a button. The full file can be found here. [link](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/trd8d5l40epkxme/AAAV2TomY8Uc6SwskBkF073wa?dl=0) @SebastianWramba

Comment: Both Values return null. @NickCatib

Comment: I think you are mixing things up. You should either use the `IBAction` OR the `prepareForSegue` method. Is the inner `prepareForSegue` even called? Actually this function should be on top level and is called by the "system" when you tap on something that has a segue defined in Interface Builder.

Comment: @SebastianWramba I don't really get it.. My intention is that when user tab onto the button called solve on the interface, prepareforsegue is being called to pass force and stiffness arrays to ViewController2. I have already built my solve button in my storyboard to push to Viewcontroller2. Will you explain to me why am i wrong?

Comment: I don't say that you're wrong per se. I'd just do it differently. Try to separate the `prepareForSegue` and `solve` function. Then in the `solve` function you call `performSegueWithIdentifier("Solve", sender: self)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created project similar to yours (using your github link) and @Sebastian Wramba is correct. You have to separate these two functions:

```
@IBAction func solve_pressed(sender: AnyObject) {
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("Solve", sender: sender)
    }

override func prepareForSegue ( segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
    if (segue.identifier == "Solve") {
        var svc = segue.destinationViewController as ViewController2

        svc.toPass = self.force
        svc.toPass2 = stiffness

    }
}
```

Okay, solved (pun intended). You have to give your segue identifier, in this particular case, "Solve". In your first view controller, select push to View Controller2, go to the fourth tab and set identifier to "Solve".

Comment: @Sebastian Wramba . Thanks! I build it as suggested, but my ViewController2 still prints an empty array [ ], instead of the values inside the arrays in my ViewController1. Any advise? Help is appreciated

Comment: well it seems like you are sending empty array for some reason...  can you confirm but logging into console that you have actual array in prepareForSegue function?

Comment: I can confirm that my arrays are with values before going into the prepareForSegue Function. But I am not not too sure how to verify my arrays are valid during the prepareForSegue function. Or how do i check? I put up a screenshot and file into a drop box link for references. [link] (https://www.dropbox.com/sh/k41rzgi893excuy/AAB62yOTqP0N0hV62demOW6Ia?dl=0)

Comment: Nice! Thanks. It works!! But can i ask, why previously when prepareForSegue is below IBAction doesn't work? Is it because the prepareForSegue is not being called when the user tap on it, since it is too "Fast"?

Comment: No, actually, the code wont look inside your function for that particular one, it will look on the scope of the view controller which doesn't have implemented prepare for segue.